# All in one PCB mount buck converter? Sounds like snake oil

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, 7805

I am on the hunt to power an ESP8266 and a relay from 12V while keeping the PCB as small as possible.

I am trying to avoid having to SMD the parts and have been advised against the LM7805 route as there is circa 350mA maximum current.

I have come across this and wondered if it's just marketing or if it would work.

[image: Part available online]

Comment: 3-pin buck regulator modules like that have been around at least 10-15 years already. They're not snake oil - as long as you buy from a reputable manufacturer or even a reputable electronic component distributor (by which I mean Digikey, Mouser, Newark, etc, and *not* Alibaba, ebay or Amazon).

Comment: Obviously only buy from well-known manufacturers and keep well within their specification.

Comment: I use these all the time. Easy to use and does the job you need. Usually a little more expensive than rolling your own converter, but cuts out a fair bit of work and my use case isn't price-sensitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a switching regulator.  Yes, it can be that small and do what it says.

Whether it's a good one that meets all the specifications is a different question.  The [company that sells it](https://www.qskj.cc/shop/product/1941758-dc-dc-mini-converter-6-5-24v-to-5v-1a-power-supply-module-qs-7805-1a-79202) doesn't even bother with a real datasheet so the thing is of questionable quality.

There are other manufacturers that make similar modules - and they do provide datasheets. [MEAN WELL makes the N7805](https://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=N78), which is very much like the module you found - except it costs more and comes from a well known company.

There are plenty of other manufacturers.  Search around and find a module with datasheet from a reputable supplier.

Comment: its looking like im going a different route and powering the relay from 12v and ill use an 7805L to power the esp via an LDO

Comment: @robbrown92 These kind of pre-made modules are far more sensible to use than 7805 though. If designing your own step-down isn't an option, then these give reasonable "bang for the buck" (har har), since they will be pre-qualified and one wouldn't expect any EMC issues originating from them. Though 7805 can double down as heating element for outdoor applications...

Comment: I've done some digging and found a part from Morson a K7805 looks like it will be an ideal solution to the problem